# How to delete checkbox text from richTextBox using chechked method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

Whenever a user click's on the checkBox controls, the text in the checkBox will be appeared on the richTextBox.text and it wasn't so hard because all I needed was :

```
 if (CBSefalexin.Checked == true)
            richTextBox1.Text += CBSefalexin.Text;
```

But now, I want to do something. Whenever user unchecked the checkbox, I want to delete that text (which recently added up to richtextBox.text) from richTextBox. It is obvious that I cannot use the code below:

```
if (CBSefalexin.Checked == true)
            richTextBox1.Text += CBSefalexin.Text;
        else
            richTextBox1.Text -= CBSefalexin.Text;
```

Because it's impossible to use "-" for strings. But I want to know if I can write that code in my project. Any suggestion so far ?
Thanks in advance.
***UPDATE***
I do not want to clean the whole of the text. I just want to delete that specific text which I just added up to richTextBox(Because I have so many checkboxes that I want to do the same things with them)

Comment: What about richTextBox1.Text = "" to clear the textbox ?

Comment: @auburg I do not want to clean the whole of the text. All I want to delete is that specific text which I just added up to my richTextBox

Comment: what about richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(CBSefalexin.Text,"") ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(CBSefalexin.Text,"")
```

This should replace just the text hat you initially set

Comment: Where should I add this text ? I mean in which events? In CheckBox_CheckedChange ?

Comment: Instead of richTextBox1.Text -= CBSefalexin.Text;